# My addEventListener() is not working causing data tables

Tags: javascript, api, datatables, addeventlistener

i tried to request data from my api, so when it clicked in the button, the button will do addEventListener,but when i using the data tables on my table, the addEventListener is not working when i clicking on 10 lines data above, here's my code

get data and inner html

```
// GET ALL DATA
const getDataUser = async () => {
    let res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/user')
    return res.json()
}

const addRowUser = async () => {

    const dataUser = await getDataUser();
    let users = dataUser.user
    let data = "";
    let no = 1;
    users.forEach((user) => {
        data += `<tr>
    <td>${no++}</td>
    <td>${user.name}</td>
    <td>${user.email}</td>
    <td>${user.address}</td>
    <td>${user.image}</td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</button> | 
        <button type="button" data-id="${user.id}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delUser">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>`;
    })
    let table = document.getElementById('userTable')
    table.innerHTML = data
    console.log(users)
}

addRowUser();
```

delete data

```
// DELETE DATA
window.onload = () => {
    const tombol = document.querySelectorAll('.delUser')
    tombol.forEach(m =>
        m.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            const id = e.target.dataset.id
            console.log('ok')
            swal({
                    title: "Are you sure?",
                    text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary data!",
                    icon: "warning",
                    buttons: true,
                    dangerMode: true,
                })
                .then((willDelete) => {
                    if (willDelete) {
                        fetch(`http://localhost:3000/user/${id}`, {
                                method: 'delete',
                                headers: {
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                },
                            }).then(res => res.json())
                            .then(res => console.log(res))
                        swal("Poof! Your imaginary file has been deleted!", {
                            icon: "success",
                        }).then((value) => {
                            document.location.reload()
                        })
                    } else {
                        swal("Your imaginary file is safe!");
                    }
                });

        })
    )
```

my html table

```
<table id="table-user" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td>No</td>
                                <td>Name</td>
                                <td>Email</td>
                                <td>Address</td>
                                <td>Image</td>
                                <td>Action</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="userTable">

                        </tbody>
```

load data tables

```
$('#table-user').DataTable()
```

Comment: The DataTable plugin will not keep the same row elements you are inserting into it when it sorts, filters paginates etc. You don't want to work with it's html yourself. instead to add rows use it's API to pass in new row data and the plugin will render the rows. For events you need to use on the rendered rows you need to use  **event delegation**

Comment: See the examples in plugin documentaion for adding rows, using ajax etc